# How to access localized string during automated UI test in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I have one more question based on my previous discussion thread of localized strings. Here is the link:
[How to do automated UI testing for system button on XCode7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947401/how-to-do-automated-ui-testing-for-system-button-on-xcode7)

Now if I switch the iOS system language to another one, I can't get the localized string since it's in different bundle. I found another thread is talking about this:
[Can't get access to string localizations in UI Test (Xcode 7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33086266/cant-get-access-to-string-localizations-in-ui-test-xcode-7)

It works good if I copy all of localized strings from target app to UI tests. But for those strings in XIBs or storyboards they are using Object ID to represent a message, it's meaningless and not readable. 
[How to make Object ID human-readable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788179/how-to-make-object-id-human-readable)

So I have to convert it first to know what it's originally before using NSLocalizedString:

```
NSLocalizedString("Help", bundle: NSBundle(forClass: AClassInYourUITests.self), comment: "")
```

Is there any easy way to resolve this issue within Xcode? If possible I wouldn't like to use these meaningless string in my code, it's difficult to know what it's.  Or I have to write a script to handle this?

To be more precise, let's have an example. Some of my localized strings in storyboard of target app are:

```
"U2v-M1-HYu.text" = "ヘルプ";
"eTC-Zg-zHl.headerTitle" = "完了";
```

If I want to do the UI tests for different languages, I can't just copy it to the UI test bundle. I need to convert it first like this:

```
"Help" = "ヘルプ";
"Done" = "完了";
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Add your `localizable.strings` file to your UI Test target

**Step 2.** Create these helper methods in your Test class (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44014704/1437096)):

```
var currentLanguage: (langCode: String, localeCode: String)? {
    let currentLocale = Locale(identifier: Locale.preferredLanguages.first!)
    guard let langCode = currentLocale.languageCode else {
        return nil
    }
    var localeCode = langCode
    if let scriptCode = currentLocale.scriptCode {
        localeCode = "\(langCode)-\(scriptCode)"
    } else if let regionCode = currentLocale.regionCode {
        localeCode = "\(langCode)-\(regionCode)"
    }
    return (langCode, localeCode)
}

func localizedString(_ key: String) -> String {
    let testBundle = Bundle(for: /*YourTestClass*/.self)
    if let currentLanguage = currentLanguage,
        let testBundlePath = testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.localeCode, ofType: "lproj") ?? testBundle.path(forResource: currentLanguage.langCode, ofType: "lproj"),
        let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: testBundlePath)
    {
        return NSLocalizedString(key, bundle: localizedBundle, comment: "")
    }
    return "?"
}
```

**Step 3.** Change `YourTestClass` in step 2 code to your test class

**Step 4.** Get your localized string by using `localizedString("String")`

**NOTE:** This doesn't seem to work for all localization strings. I have found it doesn't work for storyboard strings for me, only the `localizable.strings` file.